How to correctly handle await Swal.fire() inside a loop in an async function for dynamic SQL parameter input?
I'm developing a feature where I need to dynamically replace parameters in an SQL query based on user input. Each parameter inside $parameter$ must trigger a different Swal.fire() prompt for user input. However, I'm encountering issues where the prompts appear out of order or not as expected. I suspect the problem might be related to how I'm using await within a loop.
Here is the relevant part of my function :
const reemplazarSql = async query => {
// Other parts of the function...
else {
    const key = split[i].split(';')[0];
    if (filtrosXConsulta.has(nroConsulta)) {
        filtrosXConsulta.get(nroConsulta).push(key);
    } else {
        filtrosXConsulta.set(nroConsulta, [key]);
    }
    if (!valoresXfiltroPrimario.has(key)) {
        console.log(
            'valoresxfiltro Primario',
            valoresXfiltroPrimario,
            valoresXfiltroPrimario.has(key),
            filtrosCache.get(key)
        );
        let valIngresado;
        valIngresado = filtrosCache.get(key);
        valIngresado = await obtenerDatosUsuario(key, valIngresado);
        filtrosCache.set(key, valIngresado);
        valoresXfiltroPrimario.set(key, valIngresado);
        console.log('ValorIngresado ', valIngresado);
        console.log('modificada antes : ', modifiedSql);
        modifiedSql += valIngresado;
        console.log('modificada despues : ', modifiedSql);
    } else {
        modifiedSql += valoresXfiltroPrimario.get(key);
        console.log('modificada despues : ', modifiedSql);
    }
}

};
And here is the obtenerDatosUsuario function:
async function obtenerDatosUsuario(key, valorInicial) {
const { value: resultado, isConfirmed } = await Swal.fire({
title: <span style="font-size: 0.75em; color: black; font-weight: normal;">Ingrese ${key} </span>,
input: 'text',
inputValue: valorInicial || '',
showCancelButton: true,
confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar',
cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
});
if (resultado && isConfirmed) {
    console.log(`Resultado ingresado: ${resultado}`);
    return resultado;
}
return null;

}
i try different approaches to using async await, such as changing to .then() but i cant solve it yet
